# How to pull HTML form details in controller in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-5.4, contactus

I am working on building a form in which I want to populate the fields coming from form (which I have named posting.blade.php)

The controller which I have used for that is:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required',
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'number' => 'required',
    'city' => 'required',
    'post' => 'required'
    ]);

    Mail::send('emails.posting-message', [
    'msg'=> $request->message
    ], function($mail) use($request) {
        $mail->from($request->email, $request->name);
        $mail->to('helloworld@gmail.com')->subject('Contact Message');
    });
    return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message', 'Thank you for your message');
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

The current controller doesn't return anything as in the line `'msg'=> $request->message` there is no message in validate. But if I use

`'msg'=> $request->name` (It returns name)

I am wondering what changes I should make in the controller so that it return every field present in the validate.

I tried with this but its only returning the last value which is post.

```
   'msg'=> $request->name,
   'msg'=> $request->email,
   'msg'=> $request->number,
   'msg'=> $request->city,
   'msg'=> $request->post
```

Comment: Can we see your html form?

Comment: sure. http://jsfiddle.net/yn02581o/4/ Line# 50 to Line#95

Answer (score 1):

Don't you just want to append them all to message?

```
'msg'=> $request->name . "\r\n"
        . $request->email . "\r\n"
        . $request->number . "\r\n"
        . $request->city . "\r\n"
        . $request->post . "\r\n"
```

("\r\n" - carriage return + linefeed for emails.)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I have one more similar question. Suppose if I want to pull line#74 to line#95 details from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yn02581o/4/), how can we do that ? These are the checkboxes I am using in the form.

Comment: Are you around ?

Comment: You stated here that you want to pull the checkboxes.

Comment: Yes, I want to pull those information. Sorry for the confusion. In the question, I didn't mention that.

Comment: Since you are submitting the form directly, then you have to add a 'name' attribute to them.

Comment: I have added the attribute name here http://jsfiddle.net/yn02581o/8/ Now what I have to do in order to pull the checkbox information if the user select them.

Comment: Do this in your controller:  `if($request->has('checkbox-name'){ $value = $request->get('checkbox-name') }`